# Order by fileinfo extension and name

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm using this query:

```
Dim FilesDirsQuery = From file In
                   _directory.EnumerateFileSystemInfos()
                   Select file.Name, file.Extension
```

It gets all files and directories in the _directory. But how to order the query by extension and name?

So I found that I have to use this to order by extension:

```
Dim FilesDirsQuery = From f In
        _directory.EnumerateFileSystemInfos()
        Select f.Name, f.Extension Order By Function(f As IO.FileInfo)
                                              Return f.Extension
                                            End Function
```

And I have to use "ThenBy", but it can't be used in my example. So I tried:

```
FilesDirsQuery.OrderBy(Function(f As IO.FileInfo)
                        Return f.Extension
                       End Function).ThenBy(..)
```

But it say's that my nested function doesn't have a compatible delegate. So what should I do?

Comment: What's the type of `_directory`? Oh, I found it. `EnumerateFileSystemInfos` is only available in .NET 4 or 4.5

Comment: @DennisPalmer No, _directory is type of IO.DirectoryInfo.

Comment: Right, but the method `EnumerateFileSystemInfos` doesn't exist in .NET 3.5, so at first I thought `_directory` must be some other type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you directories, then files alphabetically.

I used `f` instead of `file` in the query because Visual Studio wanted to change `file` to `File`.

```
Dim FilesDirsQuery = From f In
                     _directory.EnumerateFileSystemInfos()
                     Select f.Name, f.Extension, isDirectory = ((f.Attributes And FileAttributes.Directory) = FileAttributes.Directory)
                     Order By isDirectory Descending, Name
```

**Edit:** (because question changed from order by type to order by extension)

To order by extension, just use this:

```
Dim FilesDirsQuery = From f In
                     _directory.EnumerateFileSystemInfos()
                     Select f.Name, f.Extension
                     Order By Extension, Name
```

**Edit 2:** Lambda functions

What you're calling a nested function, actually needs to be a Lambda function. Here's how the `OrderBy` method would be called using a Lambda:

```
FilesDirsQuery.OrderBy(Function(f) f.Extension).ThenBy(..)
```

The parameter type and return statement are implied.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say it in vb, but if you can transpose from c#, this could help you:

```
var FilesDirsQuery = from fsInfo in _directory.EnumerateFileSystemInfos()
                     let type = fsInfo.GetType()
                     orderby type
                     orderby fsInfo.Name //or fsInfo.FullName
                     select new {fsInfo.Name, fsInfo.Extension};
```

Comment: you probably shouldn't answer questions about a language with which you are not familiar.

Comment: @AndrewBarber There were no answer after half an hour, just tried to help my friend.

Comment: A half hour isn't really very long to wait for the right answer. The OP changed the question within the first half hour.

Comment: @DennisPalmer It's still OK if he helps with a c# answer, because converting from c# to vb.net is fairly simple.